# Material UI Autocomplete custom renderInput

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm following various examples from https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/ to create a custom autocomplete. I'm trying to use the `renderInput` property to use a custom input component. All of the examples I find use the `TextField` component, but I'd like to use a regular `input` component.

Problem is, the options are never displayed. I've created a demonstration here (swap `renderInput` with `renderInputWORKING` to see working version):

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-johnson-oxy7b?file=/src/App.tsx

with the following code in `renderInput`:

```
 const renderInput = (params: AutocompleteRenderInputParams) => {
    console.log(params);
    const { InputLabelProps, inputProps, InputProps } = params;
    return (
      <div>
        <label {...InputLabelProps}>foo</label>
        <input {...InputProps} {...inputProps} />
      </div>
    );
  };
```

How can I use the `<input />` component for `renderInput` prop on `<Autocomplete />`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The 4.10.1 release of Material-UI (on June 1, 2020) included a new example in the documentation for this exact case: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#custom-input.

Pull request: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/21257

---

The most useful example to look at in the documentation is the [Customized Autocomplete example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#customized-autocomplete) which uses `InputBase` instead of `TextField`. This example contains the following code for `renderInput`:

```
         renderInput={(params) => (
            <InputBase
              ref={params.InputProps.ref}
              inputProps={params.inputProps}
              autoFocus
              className={classes.inputBase}
            />
          )}
```

The `InputProps` passed to `TextField` are placed on a div that wraps the `<input>`, so most of those props are not appropriate to put directly on the `<input>` element as you were. In the code above from the documentation example, you can see that it only uses one thing from `params.InputProps` which is the `ref`. This ref is [used for controlling the anchor element](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Autocomplete/Autocomplete.js#L421) for the listbox of options. A ref is also [placed on the `<input>` itself](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.10.0/packages/material-ui-lab/src/useAutocomplete/useAutocomplete.js#L936), but that `ref` is used for very different purposes. With your code, only one of those refs was getting used.

Below is a working example (based on the [Combo Box example](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#combo-box) since your sandbox has a lot of other customizations that aren't directly related to this question) that uses `<input>` instead of `TextField`:

```
import React from "react";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default function ComboBox() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={params => (
        <div ref={params.InputProps.ref}>
          <label {...params.InputLabelProps}>My Label </label>
          <input {...params.inputProps} autoFocus />
        </div>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Autocomplete using input instead of TextField]

Answer (score 0):

We can able to writed custom renderInput in the following In my case I have writen the custom renderInput to avoide clear icon in the compoenet

```
<Autocomplete
    fullWidth={true}
    label={props.label}
    margin={'noraml'}
    multiple={false}
    name={props.name}
    isOptionEqualToValue={useCallback((option, value) => option.value === value.value, [])}
    value={props.value}
    options={props.options}
    ref={selectRef}
    id='disable-clearable'
    disableClearable
    renderInput={useCallback(params => (
        <TextField {...params} label='disableClearable' variant='standard' />
    ), [])}
    onChange={useCallback((e, v) => {
        if (typeof v === 'object' && v !== null) {
            _onChange(e, v)
        } else {
            _onChange(e, {label: ''})
        }
    }, [])}
/>
```