# React MUI - Customizing Autocomplete component by rederInput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a React MUI [Autocomplete](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete) component as the one from the official doc.

The following is the example for the countries.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

export default function CountrySelect() {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="country-select-demo"
      sx={{ width: 300 }}
      options={countries}
      autoHighlight
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
      renderOption={(props, option) => (
        <Box component="li" sx={{ '& > img': { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }} {...props}>
          <img
            loading="lazy"
            width="20"
            src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
            srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${option.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
            alt=""
          />
          {option.label} ({option.code}) +{option.phone}
        </Box>
      )}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Choose a country"
          inputProps={{
            ...params.inputProps,
            autoComplete: 'new-password', // disable autocomplete and autofill
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
}

// From https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/atlaskit-mk-2/raw/4ad0e56649c3e6c973e226b7efaeb28cb240ccb0/packages/core/select/src/data/countries.js
const countries = [
  { code: 'AD', label: 'Andorra', phone: '376' },
   ..........
   ..........
  {
    code: 'AE',
    label: 'United Arab Emirates',
    phone: '971',
  },
  
];
```

[image: Edit CountrySelect Material Demo]

During the selection, the component show a list of countries alongside some info and the corresponding icon flag.

After picking a country, the country's name is displayed in the Textfield.

From what I understood from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62110017/material-ui-autocomplete-custom-renderinput), it is possible to manipulate the property **renderInput** in order to customize the final appeareance of the component, in this example the TextField.

Is there a way to display **also the flag** near the selected country name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the icon of a selected option, you should add start `startAdornment` to `InputProps` of `TextField` component. This prop is responsible for rendering icon before the text of selected option. Then we can pass the property of a selected option to `startAdornment` to show the icon of the selected option:

```
    <Autocomplete
      value={value}
      onChange={(event, newValue) => {
        setValue(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => {
        return (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Choose a country"
            inputProps={{
              ...params.inputProps,
              autoComplete: "new-password" 
            }}
            InputProps={{
              ...params.InputProps,
              startAdornment: value ? (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <img
                    loading="lazy"
                    width="20"
                    src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png`}
                    srcSet={`https://flagcdn.com/w40/${value.code.toLowerCase()}.png 2x`}
                    alt=""
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ) : null
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    ... other props
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/selectedvalue-with-icon-cicoo3?file=/demo.js:358-471)

Comment: Hello, is it also possible to render a custom text near the flag with this approach?
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can put any react node inside `InputAdornment` component